# How to manage Facebook connect in Drupal multisite?

Tags: php, facebook, drupal, drupal-7

I have a Drupal multisite installation. It is not a common multisite installation. Long story short: I have one single database, one single setting.php and the change of theme is managed according to the site domain by the module ThemeKey. The drupal installation makes two sites working with different themes and i managed to have for them two different domains using Apache Server Alias, so that i have two sites www.foo.com and www.bar.com.

Now i'm managing the facebook registration with the module FBOauth that allows to enter only one facebook app id. In the first site, let's say www.foo.com, facebook registration works perfectly for it is connected with the facebook app which fboauth knows about. In the second site, www.bar.com, the registration doesn't work for facebook allows me to add, to a single facebook app, only *one* domain (or subdomain of it, that's not the case). I mean, in the facebook app i can enter www.foo.com, but not www.bar.com, so if i try to register from www.bar.com facebook throws a 'domain not allowed' error.

I think the correct way to deal with this is by opening a second facebook app for www.bar.com, but fbaouth allows me to enter only one app id. How can i overcome this?

EDIT: there are two variables fboauth_id and fboauth_secret. Overriding these solves the problem, but i can't do it in setting.php, there's another way?

Comment: With such a setup, there is no real “elegant” solution.

Comment: Maybe! It is not so strange, btw. In the very line I modified in the fboauth code, there was a comment saying "//TODO add multisite support" :) They are thinking about it, but not still developed.

Comment: “//TODO add multisite support” – yeah, for “real” multi-site setups probably, but in Drupal terms that means each site having its own database and settings; but as you said yourself you don’t have one of those, but are only “faking it” by using ThemeKey.

Comment: It is not so different. I was in need of two 'branches' of the same site, so this was the most suitable solution and i have two sites built on one installation, so it is a multisite. There are full modules to manage this situation: it is not so unusual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RAW SOLUTION: I solved the problem, modifying fboauth module code. I created two functions: one returning an app id, another returning an app secret, depending on the domain i'm in. Then I substituted every "variable_get('fboauth_id', '')" and "variable_get('fboauth_secret', '')" in the module files with my customized functions. It is not elegant, and i'm still interested in better solutions.

```
function fboauth_get_app_id_depending_on_domain(){
  $server_name = ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
  $server_uri =($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
  if($server_name=='www.bar.com'){
     $app_id='1234567890';
  }else{
     $app_id=variable_get('fboauth_id', '');
  }
 return $app_id;
}

function fboauth_get_app_secret_depending_on_domain(){
 $server_name = ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
 $server_uri =($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
 if($server_name=='www.bar.com'){
      $app_secret='1234567890';
 }else{
     $app_secret=variable_get('fboauth_secret', '');
 }
 return $app_secret;
}
```